# Java: Is transaction reuse in jpa a good practice?

Tags: java, transactions, entitymanager

Is it a good practice to reuse the transactions after committing it? Like after I begin a transaction and commit it, I begin it again and commit it once again. And perform rollback in case of exceptions? Is this a good practice?

Comment: I see no good explanation for it.  Why do you need the transaction twice?

Comment: In principle there's nothing against it, but you'll have to wonder what will happen to when your flow goes through many classes with a 'live' transaction. Are you passing it on, injecting it?

Comment: @Diederick Yes, I'm injecting it, whenever an object is created, it's constructor is initialized to the entity manager which the calling methods use. I'm trying to reuse the transaction as I'm trying to save the data in different tables at once and the project I'm working on, uses the same transaction everywhere. So in my scenario, I'm here saving a part of data into the table as a prerequisite in the beginning and later I use that data to form some new data and store that too.  Just wondering if that's a good practice.